# Month over Month Amount in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here's my DAX Function that gives me my total amount (say sales) for this month:

```
Current Month = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM (Budget[Amount]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL ('Calendar'), 
        'Calendar'[MonthDate]= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH (TODAY()),1)
    )
)
```

How would I be able to edit this to give me the amount for last month, so that I can compare Month-over-month?

Comment: you can check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousmonth-function-dax

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Previous Month = CALCULATE (SUM (Budget[Amount]), 
       FILTER (ALL ('Calendar'), 
             'Calendar'[MonthDate]= DATE (YEAR ( TODAY ()), MONTH (TODAY () ) , -1 )))
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the current month sales with last month, you can store the current month in a variable like below:

Last_Month_Sales = var Current_Month= MONTH(TODAY()) return  CALCULATE(SUM(Budget[Amount]),FILTER(ALL ('Calendar'),
'Calendar'[MonthDate]=Current_Month-1))